# Variance of a random variable given a statement about some limit

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance, probability-limit-theorems

Let  $X_1, X_2, ... $ be a sequence of i.i.d  random variables with mean equal to $0$, and finite variance. Find the variance $\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$ if
$$\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n} > 1\right)=\frac{1}{3}$$

I've tried researching any theorems that could help me solve this, but can't find any. Never solved anything like this, with limits and sequences of random variables, so I have $0$ idea how to even approach it.

Comment: Use the central limit theorem.

Comment: @Mason according to wikipedia, $\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} P(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n} <= 1)=\frac{2}{3}=F(\frac{1}{s})$ where s  - is the square root of variance and F  is the standard normal CDF. Did you mean this way?

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking.

Comment: @Mason thanks! But I'm currently stuck finding the solution to the equation I got in the first comment (can't calculate the integral). Wolfram gives an approximation, but is there a way to find it exactly?

Comment: No I think the solution will be in terms of $F^{-1}$.

Comment: @Mason thanks a lot!